# How to get a list of available nuget updates in the commandline?

Tags: nuget

I want to list all available updates from the nuget commandline. If I run

```
nuget update Solution.sln -verbosity detailed
```

it starts trying to update the packages immediately. I only want to list
which ones are available. How do I do this?

Comment: This is not supported by NuGet.exe

Answer (score 8):

So if you use the NuGet Powershell Console in Visual Studio, you can do `update-package -whatif` to get a list of all the packages that would be updated in the current solution.

Answer (score 4):

Also, from the NuGet Powershell Console in Visual studio, you can run:

```
PM> get-package -updates
```

It will list all updates available for all projects in the solution in a nice table format.